# С: чем отличаются однобайтовые строки от многобайтовых строк

Tags: c, строки

Встретил такое понятие как `byte string`, и `multibyte string`.

Чем они отличаются, и как эти два типа определяются?
Как я понял через `char` тип оба, но в чем отличие тогда не понятно.

Comment: http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte, http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte. Читаем до полного просветления. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Действительно, есть как однобайтовые, так и многобайтовые строки. И оба этих типа являются массивами элементов типа `char`. Но есть и разница.

В ***однобайтовой*** строке (byte string) каждый `char` - это один символ.

В ***многобайтовой*** строке (multibyte string) один символ может занимать более одного байта, т.е. быть расположенным в нескольких подряд идущих `char`.

Например, строку в кодировке *UTF-8* нужно сохранять как *многобайтовую*, поскольку один символ может занимать от 1 до 6 байт.

---

Небольшая историческая справка.

Вначале существовали только кодировки, где каждый символ кодировался не более чем одним байтом. Но поскольку нужно было отображать символы на разных языках, а 256 символов оказалось для этого мало, то возникли кодировки, где символ кодировался более чем одним байтом. Например, это *Юникод* (*Unicode*). Но Юникод тоже бывает разным. Можно всегда выделять для символа много места (массив `wchar_t`, например), а можно экономить память и сделать число байт на символ переменным, что реализует, например, *UTF-8*. Именно для таких кодировок с переменным числом байт на символ и были созданы многобайтовые строки.

P.S. Но никто не мешает использовать их и для кодировок с постоянным числом байт на символ.